# Java HTTP Get Request returns JSP Code

Tags: java, jsp, http, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to load the list of team numbers on this URL: http://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search/event?id=17351. As you can see, the page renders fine and the list of teams loads up fine.

However, when I make a HTTP request, I seem to receive raw JSP code instead of the list of teams in the response.

Is there a way to get HttpURLConnect to fetch the page after the JSP code has been fully run or am I barking up the wrong tree (i.e. need to use another method)?

My block that fetches HTTP content:

```
    public static String getURL(String urlString){
    Logger.info(String.format("Fetching URL: %s", urlString));

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestProperty("X-TBA-App-Id", APPID);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/42.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "usfirst.org, firstinspires.org");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String line = in.readLine();
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while (line != null){
            response.append(line);
            line = in.readLine();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Logger.error("Failure", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Response (snipped to the part with the JSP code):

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-2" data-field="country">Country</div>             </div>        
<% for(var i=0;i<item._source.number_teams;i++) { %>        
<div class="row">
```

Comment: If you're receiving jsp code then the server is not properly setup. What is it running? (Apache HTTPD, IIS, Tomcat, Websphere, etc....)?

Comment: I don't have control over the website I'm trying to pull data from, so I couldn't say what server they're running.

Comment: This is not a JSP source code, this is a JavaScript template - the page uses some kind of Javascript templating (can't say wich one from the first look), and loads the data for the table per AJAX.